# AssertionError: Violation of: lines.txt exists

Tags: java, file

I have a file `lines.txt` under the `Data` folder. The problem is I get an error when I put `lines.txt` as an input. The error happens at this line `SimpleReader inFile = new SimpleReader1L(inputFileName);`

I know it is something has to do with the path because it is not getting recognized, but I do not have enough experience to fix it. Can someone show me what do I have to do?

```
import components.set.Set;
import components.simplereader.SimpleReader;
import components.simplereader.SimpleReader1L;
import components.simplewriter.SimpleWriter;
import components.simplewriter.SimpleWriter1L;

public final class pp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleReader in = new SimpleReader1L();
        SimpleWriter out = new SimpleWriter1L();
        /*
         * Get input file name
         */

        out.print("Input file (with fragments): ");

        String inputFileName = in.nextLine();
        SimpleReader inFile = new SimpleReader1L(inputFileName);

        /*
         * Get initial fragments from input file
         */
        Set<String> fragments = linesFromInput(inFile);
        /*
}
}
```

**This is simpleReader1L**

```
 public SimpleReader1L(String name) {
        assert name != null : "Violation of: name is not null";
        this.name = name;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(name);
            this.rep =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // throw new AssertionError("Violation of: " + url + " is valid");
            try {
                this.rep = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                throw new AssertionError("Violation of: " + name + " exists");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new AssertionError("Violation of: " + name + " exists");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AssertionError("Violation of: " + name + " can be read");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Apparently you are using [this library](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/software/common/doc/overview-summary.html).  Is that correct?

Comment: yes, I'm using this library

Answer (score 0):

A call to `new SimpleReader1L("lines.txt")` attempts to open the file "lines.txt" in the current directory.  But the file is not in the current directory.  It is in a different directory.

Solutions:

1. Use the *correct* relative pathname for the file ... relative to the directory where are running the application<sup>1</sup>.
2. Use an absolute pathname for the file.

---

If you don't understand the meaning of or difference between relative and absolute pathnames, try reading this:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/

---

<sup>1 - Working out what that directory is can be a bit tricky.  It depends on how you are running the application, and so no.</sup>

Comment: I'm using Mac so I went to the file and copied the path and used it as an input. It did not work also. Is that what you meant? if not can you walk me through the steps please?

Comment: Did you read the link I included in my answer?  Do you understand the difference between a relative and absolute pathname?

Comment: (I don't have a Mac. So I can't give you a "step by step".  But I probably couldn't anyway because you have not explained clearly how you are running the code.  Put a clear and precise description of what you are doing **into the question**.)

Answer (score 0):

> The error happens at this line SimpleReader inFile = new SimpleReader1L(inputFileName);

It's unclear what `SimpleReader1L` expects are input. Depending on whether it takes File object or a string as fileName, you need to pass the actual object or a correct path to file as string.

---

Use absolute path (starting from root directory). e.g.

Windows: `D:\somedir\lines.txt`

Unix/Mac: `/users/<username>/home/lines.txt`

Comment: I have added what SimpleReader1L does